# MATLAB: Aggregate and compare measurements with different sampling interval

Tags: matlab, aggregation

I have measured a variable `x` in equidistant long intervals (every 10 min) and a variable `y` in non-equidistant short intervals (somewhere between every 30 s and 90 s). Timestamps (`datenum`) for both `x` and `y` are available, but they are never equal, so `intersect` doesn't work. How can I aggregate `y` (e.g. `mean(y(...))` in interval `x(i+1) - x(i))` so I can compare the two (e.g. plot them against each other or plot them with the same time-vector)?

/edit 1: Confused `x` and `y` in my last but one sentence.

/edit 2: I feel like I didn't give you enough information in the original question, sorry for that.
Many of you suggest interpolation. `x` is an average wind speed over a period of 10 minutes, not a distinct measurement. So if I say time = 07:10 and `x = 3` m/s, that means `mean(x) = 3` m/s for the period from 07:00 to 07:10.  This is why I think it's probably not the best idea to interpolate it. `y` is one of many (very noisy) other variables and I want to find out the influence of (mean) `x` on `y`. So I would either like to assign many values of `y` to one measurement of `x` (in that 10 minute period), or assign a `mean(y)` to that one measurement of `x`. I assume that the solutions are quite similar, code wise.

Comment: How about interpolating one of the results to another's time? (if the signal is not too noisy)

Comment: I thought about that. Sadly, they are quite noisy by nature and I fear that interpolation would be somewhat critical in the context of my research (for reasons not specified here).

Comment: Don't you mean aggregating `y` (as it's the longer array)?

Comment: I empathize with you on the real-world signals. Been there. The only option for actual comparison (not plotting) is interpolation. Linear is the simplest, but Matlab has many. I mostly used `spline`. Depending on your signal properties, you could first filter (lowpass, sliding average) the noisy data and then interpolate. You could also show us the data plot.

Comment: EitanT: Yes, I edited my submission. Sorry for the confusion. Dedek Mraz: Thank you for your suggestions. Please see edit 2.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @FrederikRedin: Yes, please see my comment to EitanT's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the edited (2x) question:

You are trying to estimate the value of `x` at some point that you don't have the measurement for. You have measurements before and after. The *only* thing you can do is to interpolate. What method you choose is somewhat harder to decide.

Your options are:

- [piecewise constant interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) (what I think you are suggesting)
- [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)
- [spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation)
- others

/edit: If you just want to get an average value of `y` between two `x` measurements, I suggest the following:

```
new_y = zeros(size(x));
new_y(1) = mean(y(ty<=tx(1)));
for ii=2:length(x):
        new_y(ii) = mean(y(and(ty>tx(ii-1),ty<=tx(ii))));
end
```

Maybe an even better solution would be using [hist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

```
n = hist(ty,tx)
```

Vector `n` contains the number of values of `ty` that are closest to values in `tx`. Since both are monotonous, `n` tells you how to group values in `y`. Then you can use `mat2cell` to put `y` into a cell array where each cell corresponds to one measurement of `x`. The second parameter `n` now specifies how many values to put in each cell.

```
new_y = mat2cell(y,n)
```

Comment: I'm not trying to estimate / interpolate `x`. Actually, I don't want to touch `x` at all. Sorry for not being clear enough, English isn't my first language. What I want to do is aggregate (by averaging) `n` measurements of `y` and assign them to one value / timestamp of `x`; `n` being the number of measurements for `y` I have in the interval `x` was averaged over (i.e., in a 10 minute interval before the timestamp of `x`). And no, sadly I don't have the original measurements. I think they aren't even saved at all.

Comment: I'm sorry for forcing interpolation on you but I think this is the only option if you want to do it "right". And I believe the influence of `x` on `y` can best be seen this way. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I guess we disagree on the "right way" then. ;) I'd rather omit than fabricate information, but I can of course see why one would prefer interpolation. Anyway, thank you very much for your suggestions. I will certainly try them out and compare them to EitanT's solution and come back with some results in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Follow up, as promised: Both of your solutions after the edit seem to do exactly what I want and are somewhat more flexible with respect to variable time steps than EitanT's suggestion. I have yet to find out how to work with the output of your hist()-based solution, but I'll get aorund that. So, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate values, use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
accumarray(fix(ty(:) / T) + 1, y, [], @mean)
```

Here `y` is the sampled signal, `ty` is the timestamp array and `T` is the time interval of the aggregated values (for example, `T = 10 / (24 * 60) = 0.0069` for a 10-minute interval).

Comment: Can't really get that to work, but I think this might be what I'm looking for. `Error using accumarray: Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.` You can find sample code here: http://pastebin.com/KP9nhEib . Thanks so far.

Comment: @FredS `ty` has to be a column vector, so just use `ty(:)`. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks. While this does what I want for my sample code (although it creates one entry too much, but I think I'll figure that out), I have a problem with the `/ T` part because I have a few data logger defects where sampling intervals for `x` are 20 minutes (didn't actually see that until now - very long data set, sorry). Any idea what to do in this case? I have uploaded a short part of my data here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9437411/sample.mat

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate data from x to non-equidistant timestamps (or vice versa) (see interp1 function) and compare results.

Plot:

```
plot(Time_x, x, Time_y, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of using the 1-d interpolation.

```
# make two example functions on different x bases.
x1 = [0:.023:10];
x2 = [0:1:10];
y1 = x1.^2/10;
y2 = 10 - x2.^1.3;

# convert both to a common x base (x1 in this case).
y2i = interp1(x2,y2,x1);
plot(x1,y1,x1,y2i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linear interpolation!

Its easy & fun to do yourself. The idea is: Since you know the timestamps for x, the values for x, and the values for y, (but the timestamps for y don't match that of x), you can use linear interpolation (or of higher order if you need) to interpolate/"update" values for y as if they occured at the timestamps of x. After that you can plot both x and interpolated y values against the same x timestamp vector.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation